# Cross compiling opencv project for ARM and called in go project gocv

Tags: opencv, go, cross-compiling, cgo

I compiled opencv and gocv for ARM under the host Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS follows the steps as below.

**1. Apt install arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc, arm-linux-gnueabi-g++**

**2. Compile and install opencv**

```sh
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=arm-linux-gnueabi-g++  -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../opencv/platforms/linux/arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake  ../opencv
make -j16
make install
```

After installed. A folder named `install` was created in current dir and got shared libs as below.

```sh
../arm2build/install/lib
|-- cmake
|   `-- opencv4
|       |-- OpenCVConfig-version.cmake
|       |-- OpenCVConfig.cmake
|       |-- OpenCVModules-release.cmake
|       `-- OpenCVModules.cmake
|-- libopencv_calib3d.so -> libopencv_calib3d.so.405
|-- libopencv_calib3d.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_calib3d.so.405 -> libopencv_calib3d.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_core.so -> libopencv_core.so.405
|-- libopencv_core.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_core.so.405 -> libopencv_core.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_dnn.so -> libopencv_dnn.so.405
|-- libopencv_dnn.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_dnn.so.405 -> libopencv_dnn.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_features2d.so -> libopencv_features2d.so.405
|-- libopencv_features2d.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_features2d.so.405 -> libopencv_features2d.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_flann.so -> libopencv_flann.so.405
|-- libopencv_flann.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_flann.so.405 -> libopencv_flann.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_gapi.so -> libopencv_gapi.so.405
|-- libopencv_gapi.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_gapi.so.405 -> libopencv_gapi.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_highgui.so -> libopencv_highgui.so.405
|-- libopencv_highgui.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_highgui.so.405 -> libopencv_highgui.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_imgcodecs.so -> libopencv_imgcodecs.so.405
|-- libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_imgcodecs.so.405 -> libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_imgproc.so -> libopencv_imgproc.so.405
|-- libopencv_imgproc.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_imgproc.so.405 -> libopencv_imgproc.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_ml.so -> libopencv_ml.so.405
|-- libopencv_ml.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_ml.so.405 -> libopencv_ml.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_objdetect.so -> libopencv_objdetect.so.405
|-- libopencv_objdetect.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_objdetect.so.405 -> libopencv_objdetect.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_photo.so -> libopencv_photo.so.405
|-- libopencv_photo.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_photo.so.405 -> libopencv_photo.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_stitching.so -> libopencv_stitching.so.405
|-- libopencv_stitching.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_stitching.so.405 -> libopencv_stitching.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_video.so -> libopencv_video.so.405
|-- libopencv_video.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_video.so.405 -> libopencv_video.so.4.5.4
|-- libopencv_videoio.so -> libopencv_videoio.so.405
|-- libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.4
`-- libopencv_videoio.so.405 -> libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.4
```

**3. Build gocv/cmd/version project with cgo**

```sh
CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc CXX=arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ CGO_CPPFLAGS='-I/opt/arm2build/install/include/opencv4' CGO_LDFLAGS='-L/opt/arm2build/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_video -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_photo' GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm go build -tags=customenv .
```

After do that will generate ELF

```sh
root@793d7120f9df:/opt/go/gocv/cmd/version# file version
version: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3, BuildID[sha1]=038c80350b7a0c9e72b10021c66c31c2dbb4df2c, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
```

#### My questions is how to run the ELF `version` in android with arm processor?

I copied the static libraries in `install/libs` to mobile's `/system/lib/`. copied the `version` file to `/data/local/tmp` and grant execute privilege.
Then exec the `version` got output "./version: No such file or directory".

```sh
130|cactus:/data/local/tmp # ./version
/system/bin/sh: ./version: No such file or directory
```

Comment: As i find the problem would be cgo used not exist dynamic link interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason is about dynamic link interpreter which android do not has linux platform's interpreter.
After rebuild opencv with NDK got static libs. And build go project with NDK's  clang compiler, the problem would be solved.